# how to create fresh pull request from my working branch, In the last push I was unintentionally updates the last pending PR, which has some issues

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have one pending pull request from `feature2` branch to be merged into `develop` branch, but it was just stay there due to some issues in the code.

I was worked on some other script but on same `feature2` branch (which was not a good practice, I
don't know I believe)...after I did some changes I did fresh pull from `develop` using `git pull origin develop`, resolved conflicts.. then I did push to `feature2` branch

using `git push origin feature2`

not aware that it will updates the last pull request

when I did push to `feature2` branch, all the code in the working branch i.e, `feature2` is reflecting in my last pull request(essentially updates last pr), even the uncommitted code(it was painful)...I don't want my new fresh working code to be update with my last PR(which was a mess)...

I know I can't undo my PR,
I want to raise fresh PR with the commited changes don't want to update with last PR??

Can please someone say what are my options

Comment: A pull request is from one branch to another. If you want a new PR, create a new branch.

Comment: Note that *pull requests* are add-ons provided by GitHub (one version) and Bitbucket (a different version, also called a pull request but doesn't work exactly the same). Meanwhile Git*Lab* has a similar add-on but they call them *merge requests*. You've used two tags, [tag:github] *and* [tag:bitbucket], here, but if you have questions about picky details having to do with PRs, you should use only the tag for whichever hosting system you're using.

Comment: If you have valuable comments and discussion contained in the existing PR for `feature2`, and you wish to keep them, after you make the new branch for another PR, you could reset `feature2` back to the commit you want it to point to, and force push `feature2` which will put that PR back to where it was before.

Comment: @torek It's bitbucket, I've edited tags.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If i understand correct, are these the steps?   git checkout -b "new_branch"  and delete that previous PR code(while having backup of those) (as i don't want those files my fresh PR,) and do git push origin "new_branch" and raise pr from "new_branch" to "develop" from bitbucket...